# .htaccess rewrite question

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would I change

```
http://website.com/file.php
```

to

```
http://website.com/file/
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most apache server deployments, you can create a .htaccess on the document root containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

This will work as long as "file" does not match any existing directory.

Comment: Actually the RewriteRule should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php`

Comment: Can you tell me why the CSS is removed once i put this iin?

Comment: I can check your site if it is reachable through internet.